# How to remove a lost shard in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a MongoDB cluster, I accidentally hosed a shard, I don't have a backup.  It's pretty easy to recover the data, but after issuing the removeShard command, it says it's draining. However, the shard is unreachable. I just want to tell mongo to forget about the shard. Is this possible?

Comment: You might be able to purge all references to the shard from your config servers - this is the place mongo used to map the location of your data on the different shards.

Comment: It might even be faster to simply recover the data rather then trying to trick mongo into "forgetting" about some of it's data....

Comment: Stackoverflow is a community for software developers. How to administrate a MongoDB shards is a question for database administrators. However, we have another stackexchange for database administrators which is https://dba.stackexchange.com. I already voted to migrate your question, but usually it takes a while until a mongodb administration question gets the required 5 votes for migration (a common problem, that's why we even put it into the mongodb tag description), so I would ask you to delete your question here and re-ask it on dba stackexchange.